# I just cant see what I am doing wrong with this code. php

Tags: php

This is doing my head in. I am using a newish computer and cookies are enabled. Both pages are php and don't worry about vulnerability, I have that sorted and have dumbed the extract down to make it easier to submit here.

2 pages with a simple SESSION and it wont transfer the variable. I've tried single and double quotes.

I swear on my Teddy Bear that I have the code right. Any help appreciated.

I am using Chrome to test it on.

www.website/page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();    
$_SESSION["err"]  = "ERROR: Your image was not gif, jpg, or png";
header('Location: http://www.website/page2.php');
exit();
?>
```

www.website/page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$err = ($_SESSION["err"]);
echo $err;
?>
```

And all I get is a blank page.

Comment: Your code works for me, try displaying errors with `ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your code. As commented below you should always use `die()` after a `header('Location` as script execution is not terminated.

Comment: ok, super.... I will try this and head back here to comment. many thanks

Comment: is the hostname of `page2.php` equal to the hostname of `page1.php`? Quite a dumb question, but if you're loading `http://website.com/page1.php` and redirecting to `http://www.website.com/page2.php` the cookie may not apply to both domains

Comment: Thanks Allesandro, the pages are different, not as basic as per my example. All under the one site, server. I dont think this is the problem.

Comment: Ive added the exit and still a blank page.

Comment: debugging: `var_dump($_COOKIE, $_SESSION);` immediately after `session_start();`. You should see the session cookie with the same session id.Also, you should see the required value in the session?

Comment: yes I will use this thanks Ryan

Comment: array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) "b737dbe49f047b58c480bfe9bd6acae2" } array(0) { } was the result and no idea what this is..... is the about the curl? I read that on google.

Comment: Fixed and thanks to all and Alessandro came up with the answer. The names of the variables I was storing I had cloned and they were the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are using headers, header() is using headers, and you don't have output.

So it can be the case that the server don't process everything well, because it don't know where to stop.

A solution can be: put `exit()` after the header function.

Comment: Ive added the exit and still a blank page.