# PHP sessions not persisting outside of incognito browsing

Tags: php, session

I'm having a problem with session not persisting after a redirect on my website when it's not being browsed through incognito. I've tried replacing the code  with a simple script that sets the session variable "test" with "asdasd".

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION['test'] = 'asdasd';
header("Location: ../results.php");
session_write_close();
```

The results page is as follows

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
var_dump($_SESSION);
session_write_close();
```

But whenever I try to run the script that sets the session, the data does not persist on to the results page. But when I tried testing it in Chrome's incognito mode, it works. I've tried clearing cache and restarting the browser, the data is still not persisting. What could be the reason for this?

Edit: I'll happily provide any information regarding the configurations if it's going to help

Comment: Are you a colleague of this guy? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081321/i-just-cant-see-what-i-am-doing-wrong-with-this-code-php

Comment: I am not related to him in anyway sorry

Comment: `session_regenerate_id(true);` is supposed to delete old session data isn't it?

Comment: I am not sure. I'll try removing it from the results page, and see the results

Comment: I mean the `true` parameter is called `$delete_old_session` in the PHP manual so the implication seems to be that. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: I tried removing the session_regenerate_id and it's still returning an empty array

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the `Set-Cookie` header isn't process if the `Location` header is found in the same response.

It is browser-dependent, so it may be hard to tell.

Comment: How would I go about in testing it if this is the case?

Comment: Just try to use header("Set-Cookie") and header("Location") in a page, and see if the cookie is actually stored by the browser (looking at its settings).

Comment: I tried using the setcookie() function (I'm not sure if it's the same with header("Set-Cookie"))  instead to try and pass the value but even the cookie didn't persist